# Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions

Tags: java, hibernate, session

I've got a j2ee web application and I'm using hibernate and struts2 framework.
the project works fine on local server but when I upload the application on the web and more users access it simultaneously, this error is thrown :

```
Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions
```

all of a sudden the whole hibernate system crashes and I can't execute any queries.
here is the stacktrace:

```
'org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.setCurrentSession(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:432)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.WrapVisitor.processCollection(WrapVisitor.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.WrapVisitor.processValue(WrapVisitor.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractVisitor.processEntityPropertyValues(AbstractVisitor.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.wrapCollections(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1175)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1251)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.uniqueResult(AbstractQueryImpl.java:859)
    at com.hposg.login.LoginFactory.doLogin(LoginFactory.java:31)
    at com.hposg.controller.struts.LoginAction.execute(LoginAction.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor489.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:441)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:280)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:243)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:130)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

here is the piece of code causing this:

```
public static Player doLogin(String ID, String pass) throws LoginException , BanedUser{

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Player player = (Player) session.createQuery(
                "from Player as player where player.loginName = " + "'" + ID
                        + "' and player.passWord ='" + pass + "'")
                .uniqueResult();

        if (player == null)
            throw new LoginException();
        else if (!player.getIsActive())
            throw new BanedUser();

        UserSession.getInstance();
        UserSession.addPlayer(player);

        session.beginTransaction().commit();

        return player;
    }
```

the error happens irregularly(once a week, every other day, etc), any ideas what might cause this problem?

---

here is my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
```

```
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
        jdbc:mysql://localhost/hposg?characterEncoding=UTF-8
    </property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password"></property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

  <!-- Mapping files -->

  <mapping resource="com/hposg/hibernate/resources/Player.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="com/hposg/hibernate/resources/Game.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="com/hposg/hibernate/resources/Portfolio.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="com/hposg/hibernate/resources/Purchase.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="com/hposg/hibernate/resources/Sale.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="com/hposg/hibernate/resources/Message.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="com/hposg/hibernate/resources/Admin.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="com/hposg/hibernate/resources/News.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="com/hposg/hibernate/resources/Invitation.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="com/hposg/hibernate/resources/CustomGameCreationRequest.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="com/hposg/hibernate/resources/Alert.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="com/hposg/hibernate/resources/AlertLimits.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="com/hposg/hibernate/resources/StockIndex.hbm.xml"/>      
  <mapping resource="com/hposg/hibernate/resources/HPOSG.hbm.xml"/>  
  <mapping resource="com/hposg/hibernate/resources/Tradeable.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="com/hposg/hibernate/resources/GlobalGameConfig.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="com/hposg/hibernate/resources/Announcement.hbm.xml"/>  
  <mapping resource="com/hposg/hibernate/resources/AdviserMsg.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="com/hposg/hibernate/resources/SystemConfiguration.hbm.xml"/>  
</session-factory>
```

the following is my LoginAction as an example of my strategy to use hibernate :

```
try {
            Player player = LoginFactory.doLogin(username.toLowerCase(),
                    password);

            Session lSession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()
                    .getCurrentSession();
            lSession.beginTransaction();

            lSession.lock(player, LockMode.NONE);
            player.getInbox().size();
            Collection<Message> unreadMsgs = lSession
                    .createQuery(
                            "FROM Message message WHERE Respondent.id='"
                                    + player.getId()
                                    + "' AND message.isRead=false").list();

            lSession.getTransaction().commit();

            UserSession.getInstance().addPlayer(player);
            Map session = (Map) ActionContext.getContext().get("session");
            session.put("UID", username.toLowerCase());
            session.put("TYPE", "PLAYER");
            session
                    .put("NAME", player.getName() + " "
                            + player.getFamily());
            session.put("UNREADMSGS", unreadMsgs.size());
            session.put("LAST_VIEWED_GAME_ID", 0);
            return SUCCESS;
        } catch (LoginException a) {
            addActionError(a.getMessage());
            return "error";
        } catch (Exception a) {
            addActionError(e.getMessage());
            return "error";
        }
```

Am I missing sth?
Any Ideas?

Comment: What does this do? UserSession.getInstance();
        UserSession.addPlayer(player);

Comment: Show your `LoginAction` and `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

Comment: UserSession is just a class containing a hashmap of logged in users

Comment: Is the code in addPlayer() thread safe ?

Comment: in fact this class has nothing to do with hibernate, I don't save this object. it's just a container to keep online users. but your point seems to be a promising lead! I didn't consider thread safety in the whole project at all! have you got any other specific tip on this?

Answer (score 2):

Your code shows you create 2 transactions.... try this:-

```
public static Player doLogin(String ID, String pass) throws LoginException , BanedUser{

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

        ...

        tx.commit();

        return player;
    }
```

Comment: holy sh*t! seems pretty plausible. you're right buddy. (we should do some business with the programmer of this part! :D). but outta curiosity, why this doesn't happen per doLogin and the error happens irregularly?

Comment: unfortunately the problem is still out there :( I checked every single part of the code and changed all the  session.beginTransaction().commit();
 to  session.getTransaction().commit();, but this situation happens again.

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm that you are using XWork action class as Spring bean?
If that's the case, probably you forgot to follow the instruction in the Struts2/Spring, that when you have action bean as Spring bean (in the Dependency Injection controller)...
You need to declare the bean as non-singleton!
in the  declaration ensure you have **singleton="false"** attribute.

What happens if you forgot to do this? One user accessing  the same action, everything is ok. More than 1 user accessing your beans, you have race condition within the singleton bean. I suspect that's really what happened in your application.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, actually I'm not using spring at all, but I do use struts actions as my controllers. I don't have any singleton object either but there is one class (named HPOSG) in which I've got plenty of static methods, highly probable to be accessed simultaneously. these methods do not manipulate any data and they merely operate as a bridge between hibernate and business classes. in the whole app whenever I need a collection or sth, I ask these methods to provide them for me.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently using merge will probably fix the problem

```
myInstance = (myInstanceClass) Session.merge(myInstance);
```